# how to get the row of another table that has one to one relationship in room database

Tags: android-room

```
@Entity(tableName = "expenseCat")
public class ExpenseCatEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String category;





@Entity(tableName = "expenseDetails")
public class ExpenseDetailsEntity {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int detailsId;
    private int expenseCatId;
    private String notes;
    private String amount;
    private String date;





public class CatWithDetails {
    @Embedded
    public ExpenseCatEntity cat;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "expenseCatId"
    )
    public ExpenseDetailsEntity details;

}
```

[images of two tables with data in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOAaV.png)

i want to get category name from 1st table and other details from second table .
so when i pass detailsId =2 i should get like this:
 DAMAGE mobile 8000 02 Jun 2020

but whatever detailsId i pass i always get:
DAMAGE lotion 450 03 Jun 2020

below is my code in Dao

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM expenseCat AS c INNER JOIN expenseDetails AS d ON  c.id = d.expenseCatId WHERE d.detailsId = :id")
    CatWithDetails getCatAndDetailsById(int id);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get ExpenseDetailsEntity (may be not, but that was in your question):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM expenseDetails WHERE detailsId = : detailsId")
public List<ExpenseDetailsEntity> getExpenseDetailsById(int detailsId);
```

If you've meant to get CatWithDetails you can't set filter on ExpenseDetailsEntity in usual way (using Relation), so you have to use tables' join:

```
@Query("SELECT expenseCat.id, expenseDetails.detailsId, expenseDetails. expenseCatId FROM expenseCat INNER JOIN expenseDetails ON expenseCat.id = expenseDetails.expenseCatID WHERE expenseDetails.detailsId = :detailsId")
public List<CatWithDetails> getCatWithDetailsById(int detailsId);
```

**UPDATED**

If you change your CatWithDetails to:

```
public class CatWithDetails {
    @Embedded
    public ExpenseDetailsEntity details;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "expenseCatId",
            entityColumn = "id"
    )
    public ExpenseCatEntity cat;
}
```

then you can use Relation with condition and query would be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM expenseDetails WHERE detailsId = : detailsId")
CatWithDetails getCatWithDetailsById(int detailsId);
```

Comment: hello, i tried your code but it only returns row which detailsId is 3. whatever detailsId i pass it doesnt effect. i have editted my post for better understanding

Comment: It's strange, it should work, it's a simply query. Can you "double check" that you've tested it right? You can also debug the query in SQLite browser.

Comment: What you can also try - is to remove Relation annotation from your `CatWithDetails` class and use there `embedded` instead

Comment: added another possible way

Comment: hello, after removing Relation code works.

can you tell me why it works , or any documentation

Comment: I'll try) Rooms asks SQLite get some columns in query. Getting them it tries to map this columns according to the return type of the method. You can use any POJO as a result type and Room will do its best to return this POJO. But if you use Relation annotation, Room gets the result of this query and asks SQLite for another query - to the second related table. It seems that in first query Room gets one row, but in second query there is no filter any more, just left  join. So I think Room gets 3 rows as result and return first of them. If you remove Relation - there would be no second query